# Help understanding if $f(n)=\theta(g(n))$?

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, analysis-of-algorithms

I'm being asked to evaluate if $f(n)$ is a member of $\theta(g(n))$.

$() =(4 × )^{150} + (2 ×  + 1024)^{400}\,$ vs. $\,() = 20 × ^{400} + {( + 1024)}^{200}$

From what I understand, we should ignore the constants and focus on the highest power in both equations, so in this case it would evaluate to $f(n) = {n}^{400}$ and $g(n) = {n}^{400}$, which means we can find constants $c_1$ and $c_2$ that will satisfy the condition and conclude that $f(n)$ is a member of $g(n)$.

But I don't think this is right.

When we consider the formula $0 \le c_1 \cdot g(n) \le f(n) \le c_2\cdot g(n)-$ should we consider only the highest orders or take into consideration the whole function?

Confused and would like some clarity, thanks!

Comment: I formatted your equations using [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Let me know if I made any errors.

Comment: Why do you think  that's not right?

Comment: from other examples i see, when evaluating  0≤1⋅()≤()≤2⋅(), they use the full expression of f(n) instead of just the highest order. My confusion primarily surrounds this and whether I should evaluate using w/o constants + highest order or as a function as a whole.

Comment: You should use the whole functions if you want to directly apply the definition of $\Theta$-notation; the lower-order terms will constrain your choice of the constants $c_1$ and $c_2$. But it's also a theorem that for polynomials, the final result (i.e. whether $f\in\Theta(g)$ or not) only depends on the degrees.

Comment: thank you @Karl